# Sharing Apple Tether (USB) over Ethernet

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, iphone

I've had a lot of issues sharing my apple tethered iphone (Usb) to an ethernet device. The device is seeing the windows 10 laptop but not the internet. The computer is serving a local IP address but it's different than the connection with the iphone (expected).

I tried downloading connectify but I don't want to buy the paid version

Comment: USB tethering should work "as is" on an iPhone, you shouldn't have to install anything, except a driver on your PC to accomodate the use of the iPhone as a modem. Go to Device Manager, find your iPhone in the list (could be listed as "Other devices" on top), right-click on it, and Update driver. You may have to restart your PC (usually not), with the iPhone still plugged in, and USB tethering turned on (it shouldn't turn itself off if you restart the PC; it will if you shutdown the PC).

Comment: The USB tethering on the iPhone works fine so long as iTunes is open. The computer is not sharing the connection- despite having tried to set the iPhone connection as "shared" and even bridging the ethernet interface (for the Raspberry Pi), I can't get internet on the Pi

Comment: This is a completely different situation you're describing, and I strongly encourage you to edit your question and add those details about your wanting to share your Internet connection with another device via ICS. If you have to leave iTunes open to make your USB tethering work, then so be it. Is your iPhone jailbroken?